# How to do DRM for ePub files?

Tags: encryption, epub, drm

I am going to create a mobile book store for a very specific group of people. Since ePub is just compressed HTML, it's not secure enough. Anyone can access it if I extract the files to SD card. I don't want users copy the E-books around because I sell them for money.

I can parse the file and save it to a database. But I wondered if there is standard way for managing ePub DRM?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of protection you are looking for?

- just watermarking because epub DRM is hard.
- Password protection.
- Encrypted files.

From what i know you are trying to do something which is in the area of R&D plus challeging, at one side you will need to develop content encryption engine and other side a reader which will read encrypted content, these readers should also be supported in major os and mobile plateforms.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to use a DRM server solution. [Adobe Content Server 4](http://www.adobe.com/products/content-server.html) is the leading system for this, used by Google Books, Barnes & Noble etc. though it can be a bit expensive to purchase a license and setup your own server. You can also use a SaaS service like [EditionGuard](http://www.editionguard.com) to use it cost effectively, though you'll be using a shared environment in that case which may or may not fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The Readium LCP DRM is on the market since 2017 and is now deployed in most countries. It is non-proprietary and does not break the accessibility of EPUB ebooks. It is replacing the obsolete Adobe DRM, step by step.

See https://www.edrlab.org/readium-lcp/ and more especially https://www.edrlab.org/readium-lcp/certified-apps-servers/ for more info.